# Cocos2d beginner objc_msgSend EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I'm developing my first app for iOS with Cocos2d in Objective C. I'm new to objective c but I tried to google around but I cannot find solution for this general problem.

```
-(void)accelerate{
     moveSpeed = 720.0 / 3.0;

     [self stopAllActions];
     _moving = FALSE;
     CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:_walkAnimFrames delay:0.066f];
     self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
     CGPoint loc = ccp(500, 200);
     [self playerMoveTo:loc];
 }

-(void)playerMoveTo:(CGPoint)moveLocation{
     CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(moveLocation, self.position); //here is EXC_BAD_ACCESS
     float distanceToMove = ccpLength(moveDifference);
 }
```

and this is the way i call Player1 accelerate from my Game Scene:

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
    [self.Player1 accelerate];
}
```

Player1 is in my gameScene :

```
//implementation
@synthesize Player1 = _Player1;

//header
@property (nonatomic,retain) TPlayer *Player1;
```

Thank you for your patience and help. I wasn't sure what part of code i should put here so please tell me what and I will add it.

Simon

**EDIT 1:**
Player1 is allocated in init function of game scene. TPlayer is subclass of CCSprite :

```
_Player1 = [[TPlayer alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"walk2"];
```

And EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens on this line:

```
CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(moveLocation, self.position);
```

Comment: On what line does the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur?

Comment: Also where do you alloc Player1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.position might be crashing as was mentioned because of memory issues.  Self might be getting deallocated on you.  What version of Xcode are you running?  In the latest version the @synthesize is unnecessary as properties are automatically synthesized for you.  You might also consider converting your project to ARC.  I have done it with my Cocos2D project and I'm happy I did.

You could try:

```
_Player1 = [[[TPlayer alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"walk2"] autorelease];
```

or manually bump up the reference count after initializing it:

```
[self.Player1 retain];
```

To see if that helps.  This is why I like ARC :)

Answer (score 0):

- properties should start with lower case letters (and be camelCased)
- you show where you @synthesize the property, not where you actually allocate an instance.

Something like:

```
_player1 = [[Player alloc] init];
```

Hard to say much more without seeing the backtrace and the definition of `ccpSub()`.   Best guess is that `self.position` is returning a nonsense value making `ccpSub()` go off the rails.   Less likely is that `self` is over-released, but still viable enough to allow a method dispatch that subsequently crashes on the call to `[self position]`.

Comment: thank you... however i think it has to do something with not cleaning memory. I realized i can declare in playerMoveTo only one variable. When I declare second one it fails...Do you have small hint for me where should I look for problem ..?

Answer (score 0):

You got solution for crash now right...But ur moveTo function is not correct.

```
-(void)playerMoveTo:(CGPoint)moveLocation{
     CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(moveLocation, self.position); //here is EXC_BAD_ACCESS
     float distanceToMove = ccpLength(moveDifference);

     [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:moveLocation]];

 }
```